# Surjectivity of Neumann trace in $H^1_0$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a Lipschitz domain. The Neumann trace operator is surjective as $H^1(\Omega)\rightarrow H^{-\frac 1 2}(\partial\Omega)$ by construction. How about as $H^1_0\rightarrow H^{-\frac 1 2}$?

Comment: $H_0^1$ functions are zero on the boundary.

Comment: I'm thinking of (sorry for not being rigorous enough in the first place) Neumann trace as mapping equivalent to $u \mapsto \boldsymbol n \cdot \nabla u$ for smooth stuff, where $\boldsymbol n$ is the boundary normal. So yes, $H^1_0$ functions are zero on the boundary, but Neumann traces are necessarily not.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Still, don't you define this trace as $\lim n\cdot \nabla u_n$ for smooth approximations $u_n\to u$, which can be taken to be zero near the boundary if $u\in H_0^1$, so you're getting zero after all.

Comment: They can, but I'd like to have $n\cdot \nabla u$  to be an arbitrary trace space function.

Comment: My point is that $n\cdot \nabla u$ needs interpretation for an arbitrary $u\in H_0^1$, and if you follow the usual path of defining this via approximations, then it's necessarily zero on $H_0^1$.

Comment: It cant be. Choosing $u(x) = |x|^2-1$ which is in $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap C^\infty$ when $\Omega = \{|x|<1\}$ leads to $n\cdot \nabla u = 2$.

Comment: OK, so what this shows is that the map $u\mapsto n\cdot\nabla u$ does not extend continuously to $H_0^1$ (from smooth functions). But then how do you define the trace of $u$ for an arbitrary $u\in H_0^1$?